# How to disable different checkboxes in same html?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="Page1">
    <p><strong><em>(*) 1 ) Page 1 Question 1</em></strong>
    </p>
</div>
<br>
<br>


<div id="Checklist1B7">
    <table class="c1">
        <tr>
            <td width="1%"><label class="c1"><input id="QUESTION1A1" name="S1A" type=
            "checkbox"></label>
            </td>

            <td width="15%">
                <div class="c2">
                    <label class="c4" for="QUESTION1A1">Strongly Disagree</label>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td width="1%"><label class="c2"><input id="QUESTION1A2" name="S1B" type=
            "checkbox"></label>
            </td>

            <td width="15%">
                <div class="c2">
                    <label class="c5" for="QUESTION1A2">Disagree</label>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td width="1%"><label class="c3"><input id="QUESTION1A3" name="S1C" type=
            "checkbox"></label>
            </td>

            <td width="15%">
                <div class="c2">
                    <label class="c6" for="QUESTION1A3">Undecided</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td width="1%"><label class="c1"><input id="QUESTION1A4" name="S1D" type=
            "checkbox"></label>
            </td>

            <td width="15%">
                <div class="c2">
                    <label class="c4" for="QUESTION1A4">Agree</label>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td width="1%"><label class="c2"><input id="QUESTION1A5" name="S1E" type=
            "checkbox"></label>
            </td>

            <td width="15%">
                <div class="c2">
                    <label class="c5" for="QUESTION1A5">Strongly Agree</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", function(e) {
var num_checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
if (num_checked > 2) {
alert("sorry, you have already selected more than max !" );
$(e.target).attr('checked',false);
}
});
</script>

<p><strong><em>2 ) Page 1 Question 2</em></strong>
</p>
<br>
<br>


<div id="Checklist2B7">
    <table class="c1">
        <tr>
            <td width="1%"><label class="c1"><input id="QUESTION2A1" name="S2A" type=
            "checkbox"></label>
            </td>

            <td width="15%">
                <div class="c2">
                    <label class="c4" for="QUESTION2A1">Monday</label>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td width="1%"><label class="c2"><input id="QUESTION2A2" name="S2B" type=
            "checkbox"></label>
            </td>

            <td width="15%">
                <div class="c2">
                    <label class="c5" for="QUESTION2A2">Tuesday</label>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td width="1%"><label class="c3"><input id="QUESTION2A3" name="S2C" type=
            "checkbox"></label>
            </td>

            <td width="15%">
                <div class="c2">
                    <label class="c6" for="QUESTION2A3">Wednesday</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td width="1%"><label class="c1"><input id="QUESTION2A4" name="S2D" type=
            "checkbox" value="4"></label>
            </td>

            <td width="15%">
                <div class="c2">
                    <label class="c4" for="QUESTION2A4">Thursday</label>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td width="1%"><label class="c2"><input id="QUESTION2A5" name="S2E" type=
            "checkbox"></label>
            </td>

            <td width="15%">
                <div class="c2">
                    <label class="c5" for="QUESTION2A5">Friday</label>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td width="1%"><label class="c3"><input id="QUESTION2A6" name="S2F" type=
            "checkbox"></label>
            </td>

            <td width="15%">
                <div class="c2">
                    <label class="c6" for="QUESTION2A6">Saturday</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td width="1%"><label class="c1"><input id="QUESTION2A7" name="S2G" type=
            "checkbox" value="7"></label>
            </td>

            <td width="15%">
                <div class="c2">
                    <label class="c4" for="QUESTION2A7">Sunday</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", function(e) {
var num_checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
if (num_checked > 4) {
alert("sorry, you have already selected more than max !" );
$(e.target).attr('checked',false);
}
});
</script>

<table class="c2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="c5">
                <label class="c5"><button type="submit"><label class=
                "c5">NEXT</label></button></label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<div class="c9">
    <label>1</label>
</div>


<p id="demo">
</p>
```

If more than 2 checkboxes has been checked I want to disable the first question's checkboxes and it's working but my main problem is, If it happens it block to select all of the checkboxes on the same page.But you have to check less than 4 for question two.

Comment: Of course I tried myself actually I don't understand this site.I said " I need help" but all of the people firstly interrogate me.

Comment: So does anyone help me ?

Comment: You should read the [help] if you don't understand. Everything is explained there. Tl;Dr we're not really here to help **you**, this is a resouce to help **everyone**. Your questions and answers are expected to be helpful to multiple people, not just you.

Comment: Possibly worth reading the post on the [help vampire problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem). Don't be a help vampire.

Comment: ok thanks for your advice i'm reading help center now and could you please help all of the people who look here :)

Answer (score -2):

if you target `input[type=checkbox]` then it will point to every check box in the DOM

so i made the name of all checkbox's in each question to be same

```js
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=x-mac-turkish" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/styles/_reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/styles/main3.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <div id="Page1">
        <p><strong><em>(*)  1 ) Page 1 Question 1</em></strong></p>
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <div id="Checklist1B7">
        <table class="c1">
            <tr>
                <td width="1%">
                    <label class="c1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="S1" id="QUESTION1A1" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <div class="c2">
                        <label for="QUESTION1A1" class="c4">
                            Strongly Disagree</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="1%">
                    <label class="c2">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="S1" id="QUESTION1A2" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <div class="c2">
                        <label for="QUESTION1A2" class="c5">
                            Disagree</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="1%">
                    <label class="c3">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="S1" id="QUESTION1A3" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <div class="c2">
                        <label for="QUESTION1A3" class="c6">
                            Undecided</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="1%">
                    <label class="c1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="S1" id="QUESTION1A4" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <div class="c2">
                        <label for="QUESTION1A4" class="c4">
                            Agree</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="1%">
                    <label class="c2">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="S1" id="QUESTION1A5" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <div class="c2">
                        <label for="QUESTION1A5" class="c5">
                            Strongly Agree </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", function(e) {
        var QUS1 = $("input[name=S1]:checked").length;
        if (QUS1 > 2) {
            alert("sorry, you have already selected more than max !");
            $(e.target).attr('checked', false);
        }
         var QUS2 = $("input[name=S2]:checked").length;
        if (QUS2 > 4) {
            alert("sorry, you have already selected more than max !");
            $(e.target).attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
    </script>
    <p><strong><em>2 ) Page 1 Question 2</em></strong></p>
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <div id="Checklist2B7">
        <table class="c1">
            <tr>
                <td width="1%">
                    <label class="c1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="S2" id="QUESTION2A1" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <div class="c2">
                        <label for="QUESTION2A1" class="c4">
                            Monday</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="1%">
                    <label class="c2">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="S2" id="QUESTION2A2" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <div class="c2">
                        <label for="QUESTION2A2" class="c5">
                            Tuesday</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="1%">
                    <label class="c3">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="S2" id="QUESTION2A3" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <div class="c2">
                        <label for="QUESTION2A3" class="c6">
                            Wednesday</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="1%">
                    <label class="c1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="S2" value="4" id="QUESTION2A4" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <div class="c2">
                        <label for="QUESTION2A4" class="c4">
                            Thursday</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="1%">
                    <label class="c2">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="S2" id="QUESTION2A5" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <div class="c2">
                        <label for="QUESTION2A5" class="c5">
                            Friday</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="1%">
                    <label class="c3">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="S2" id="QUESTION2A6" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <div class="c2">
                        <label for="QUESTION2A6" class="c6">
                            Saturday</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="1%">
                    <label class="c1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="S2" value="7" id="QUESTION2A7" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <div class="c2">
                        <label for="QUESTION2A7" class="c4">
                            Sunday</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    
    <table class="c2">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="c5">
                    <label class="c5">
                        <button type="submit">NEXT
                        </button>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="c9">
        <label>1</label>
    </div>
    </form>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```